# Steam trade bot - TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

So, I'm in a rough spot. I'm currently trying my luck with a steam bot, yet I'm encountering a issue I seem to be unable to solve myself.

First, I would like to say that this works when I'm using a database hosted elsewhere, but when I'm using the MySQL server running on localhost, this issue is appearing.

The issue is the following:

```
/home/bot1/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:82 throw err; ^ TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined at Query._callback (/home/bot1/bot1.js:711:143) at Query.Sequence.end (/home/bot1/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:96:24) at Query.ErrorPacket (/home/bot1/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:94:8) at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/bot1/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:271:23) at Parser.write (/home/bot1/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:77:12) at Protocol.write (/home/bot1/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16) at Socket. (/home/bot1/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:96:28) at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17) at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:163:16) at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:126:10)
```

The issue that the Query callback is leading to is:

```
someVar = rows[0].playersCount;
```

The full code for this part is:

```
mysqlConnection.query('SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT userid) AS playersCount FROM game' + current_game, function(err, rows){
    someVar = rows[0].playersCount;
    console.log('Current Players: ' +someVar);
    if(someVar == 2 && items.length > 0 && endtimer==-1) {
        console.log('Found 2 Players');
        endtimer = setTimeout(EndGame,GameTime*1000);
        mysqlConnection.query('UPDATEgamesSETstarttime=UNIX_TIMESTAMP() WHEREid` = \'' + current_game + '\'', function(err, row, fields) {});
    }
});
```

When I run the query `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT userid) AS playersCount FROM game2` in this case, it returns with `playersCount 1`

I'm having a hard time to see what causes the issue, any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

what the line `Cannot read property '0' of undefined` means is that you are trying to access the property '0' of an undefined variable. from looking at your code, the undefined variable is `rows`, which means you probably have some issue with your query. Since you don't check the `err` variable in your callback, you can't tell.

The good practice for such callback methods is to first verify it went well (by checking if `err` is defined). this will allow you to understand better what went wrong, and also for your code to better handle errors:

```
mysqlConnection.query('SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT userid) AS playersCount FROM game' + current_game, function(err, rows){
    if (err) {
       // first check if there's an error and mitigate it
       ...
       ...
       return;
    }
    // if we got here, there's no error, so we know rows is defined and can get to work
    someVar = rows[0].playersCount;
    console.log('Current Players: ' +someVar);
    if(someVar == 2 && items.length > 0 && endtimer==-1) {
        console.log('Found 2 Players');
        endtimer = setTimeout(EndGame,GameTime*1000);
        mysqlConnection.query('UPDATEgamesSETstarttime=UNIX_TIMESTAMP() WHEREid` = \'' + current_game + '\'', function(err, row, fields) {});
    }
});
```

Comment: Do i need to do any changes in your code? cause when i pasted it i get another error that is impossible to read

Comment: Well, you need to handle the error... Put your error handling instead of my `...`